# How to create a variable in my Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Instead of me having to type out each name in the array above. How could I put that array into a variable? For example other programming languages I could just do var array = {“dog”,”cat”, “tiger”}. Now my items are stored in array.

```
=SUMIFS(AttendanceExport!$O:$O,AttendanceExport!$N:$N,'Revenue Output'!$B10,AttendanceExport!$J:$J,{"dog","cat","tiger","bear"}
```

Is it possible in Excel?

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't with formulas.

But what you can do is put the values in a range of cells and use this in array:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(AttendanceExport!$O:$O,AttendanceExport!$N:$N,'Revenue Output'!$B10,AttendanceExport!$J:$J,$A$1:$A$4))
```

Where `$A$1:$A$4` is the location of the items.

This needs to be entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

If you don't mind the hard coded this can be normally entered:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(AttendanceExport!$O:$O,AttendanceExport!$N:$N,'Revenue Output'!$B10,AttendanceExport!$J:$J,{"dog","cat","tiger","bear"}))
```

Comment: The part I missed was the CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER. I didn't know I needed that before. It works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to VBA in Excel.
'Dim variable As Integer' is the format to declare a variable.

[image]

[Here](https://powerspreadsheets.com/declare-variables-vba-excel/) is a link to help you better understand.